# DynamoDB TTL Metric

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have TTL set for 60 minutes. For the past 1 month or so it was working fine, records were deleted within less than 20 mins of TTL expiration. But lately (since this week) some (not all) takes up to 3 hours to delete after TTL expired.

I understand it can take a max of 48 hours, but my customer is asking for prove or justification to the current TTL behavior. Just saying IO workload influences TTL is not enough.

What metric can I use or look at to provide concrete evidence to current TTL's behavior? Is there any benchmark, eg IO load of N will cause N hours of delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no publicly available way to determine the time it will take for TTL to delete your items.  The 48 hours isn't guaranteed either.

You'll find anecdotal evidence online regarding the behavior of TTL under different scenarios (e.g. large tables vs small, other processing happening in your account, etc.), but no official guidance that will answer the question your client is asking.

If your client is unsatisfied the ambiguity around TTL, perhaps they should be exploring other solutions like implementing delete in your application logic.

Comment: In addition, DynamoDB is using excess capacity in the service to expire items and at no extra charge, unlike a normal delete.